# Unable to connect to mysql database in nodejs application in gcp

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, cpanel

I am unable to connect to my database hosted on cPanel from my Nodejs application in Google Cloud Platform.

I used Google Cloud Platform Cloud Shell, First I clone the application, second I run the command npm install and then npm start.

Application was unable to start when I run npm start.

Here's the error I am getting in Google Cloud Platform :-

```
/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'ejekanshjain'@'35.185.177.100' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ejekanshjain/pams-rest-api/db/db.js:14:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pams-rest-api@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pams-rest-api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ejekanshjain/.npm/_logs/2020-01-06T05_34_54_117Z-debug.log
```

Here's is my db file in nodejs :-

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()

// Create connection to mysql database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 111.118.214.167,
    user: ekanshjain,
    password: password,
    database: ekansh_db
})

// Open the MySQL connection
try {
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) throw err
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error connecting to DB", err)
}

module.exports = connection
```

Can anyone suggest me why I am getting this and how could I solve this?

Comment: The host IP in the error is different from the db file.

Comment: Your error typically means one of the following 1) wrong username/password 2) you have not granted privilege to the username. 3) accessing the wrong host